# What happens if an object has a negative electrical charge and it is touched to an object with a neutral charge?

Tags: charge

I am a beginner in this subject and trying to understand the basics.

If I rub my feet on a carpet and pick up additional negative charge on my body and touch a neutrally charged object, say a piece of metal, will the excess electrons in my body not flow into this object because it is neutrally charged?

Comment: Charge will redistribute.

Comment: Nature looks for a balance, pressure, charge, water level etc

Answer (score 6):

When a negatively charged object is brought in contact with a neutral object, then the charges will redistribute and try to get balanced.
On contact, the charges will distribute so that the potential difference between them becomes zero, that's both have same potential.

This is in accordance with:
\$V=Q_1/C_1= Q_2/C_2\$

\$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ are the capacitances. \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ are the new charge distribution. And \$Q_1+Q_2 \$ = net charge at the beginning before making the contact.

Comment: The idea here is right, but no, you *cannot* simply divide by two.  The actual share of excess charge on each will be proportionate to its capacitance, as when electrically connected they will end up with equal voltages, not equal charges and C=QV so V=Q/C and Q1/C1 must equal Q2/C2.

Comment: Hmm yah. I think you r right. I will update thanks.

Comment: The above is assuming you are touching a conductor of course.  Touching a good insulator such as glass might not redistribute much of the charge.